# Execute a phony target with no dependencies first in a parallel make?

Tags: makefile

In parallel make, the target: dependency should be a 1:1 so that the order of execution will be same as make with no -j.
I have a phony target that has no dependencies that I want to execute prior to all other targets:

```
 .PHONY: makeDirectories 
 makeDirectories:
   make -p /path-to-directory
```

This target does not require any dependency but is needed to be executed first in a parallel make.
The solution that I have found is the following:

```
-include makeDirectories
```

Which works. But is it the only way to make sure the PHONY target `makeDirectories` is executed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to make all your targets depend on its directory. E.g.:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.o : %.cc | $$(dir $$@) # <---- order-only dependency on the directory

% : # must be the last pattern rule
    mkdir -p $@
```

---

Yet another approach is to create the directories using `$(shell ...)` function:

```
objdir := release
$(shell mkdir -p ${objdir})
```

Comment: I would be very careful with the "match-anything" pattern rule in the first example.  These add complication and definitely will slow down make.  I know this is just an example but it doesn't really make sense as-is: a simple pattern rule like `%.o : %.c` means that the `.o` file must be in the same directory as the `.c` file so there's no need for mkdir.  A pattern rule that might need a directory created would look like `dir/%.o : %.c` and so you can write it `dir/%.o : %.c | dir` explicitly: no need for secondary expansion and match-anything rules.

Comment: @MadScientist You are right, I normally have rules like `${objdir}/%.o : ${srcdir}/%.cc`, however, it needs to recreate the directories found under `${srcdir}` in `${objdir}`, so that in real world projects one does need the order-only dependency on the directory.

Comment: @MadScientist I have been thinking about a way to mark certain targets in makefile, so that `make` automatically creates the directories for targets. It is a common nuisance having to deal with directory creation in makefiles.

Comment: I didn't mean to say you didn't need the order-only prerequisite.  Only that you don't need to use secondary expansion or a match-anything rule.  You can just list the directory directly in the order-only prerequisite.

Comment: @MadScientist I understand. My point is that under `${srcdir}` there is a directory structure that needs to be replicated in `${objdir}` and for that it needs the secondary expansion.